# AWS API Gateway GET response always cached

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

> Update: I figured it out, please see the answer post below.

I have an AWS API Gateway api defined with various resources and various GET and POST methods.

Everything works mostly fine.
POSTs are going through.
GETs return a response (JSON payload) except that the returned value seems to be a **cached** value.

My GET api calls a Lambda function that calls a query to RDS.
I can confirm my responses are stale because:

- When I manually Query the RDS, I get the updated value
- I have Cloud Watch logs enabled and the lambda function does not get called (I believe I have it set up correctly because when I test invoke the lambda, I can get Cloud Watch logs)

It did refresh once, but I think that was because I crossed some (like 1hr) caching threshold or something.

I understand that API Gateway generates a CloudFront behind the scenes.
And I feel that this is what is doing the caching. But that's just a guess and I have no proof. Maybe some kind of default caching TTL?

I obviously have caching turned off on my API Gateway stage.
I even tried enabling it, setting the TTL to 1, flushing the cache, and disabling cache again.
Each stage of that testing still returned the stale values.

I do not know if it is relevant, but additional details:

- I have CORS enabled ("*")
- I have Cognito authorizers enabled
- I pass in the JWT token via the Authorization header (this is all working fine)

Is there some header I'm supposed to pass to request an uncached value?
I went to CloudFront, but here are no configurations there.

All other posts on API Gateway caching seem to be about caching not working or people asking about cache key specificity.
I haven't seen anything about the value ALWAYS being cached no matter what. So I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Any help or debugging tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so I feel like an idiot for answering my own question but hopefully it helps someone one day.

This was not an API Gateway caching issue.
The problem was a pymysql connection & lambda session caching issue.

My Lambda was using pymysql to query the MySQL RDS.
Per recommended performance reasons, I reused the connection across lambdas (meaning I did not close the connection each time).

The solution was to call

`conn.commit()`

after I did my fetchall()

What was happening was that my subsequent calls were returning a cached query result (termed a **consistent read**. Thanks! @Michael - sqlbot) I believe I probably had more than one lambda containers or something so when I was inactive for a while (ie busy reading stackoverflow posts), the lambda would unload. Then my next API gateway attempt would reinitialize a fresh lambda handler and a branch new connection would be created (without a cache). So this is why it seems to "sometimes work, then stop".

Apologies if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: *"were returning a cached query result."*  More correctly, it sounds like they were returning a **consistent read**.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I am packaging a Flask app with Serverless. Flask/SQLAlchemy should handle any session invalidations and cleanups so I am a loss for my side of the issue but I believe it is also Lambda (Flask) -> RDS that is the issue in the call chain

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking and answering your own question.  I had the same issue and was pulling hair out trying to find which API Gateway setting was caching the result.